# How to not show title attribute in some cases with razor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I only want to show my title attribute in some cases. I don't want it to show when the condition is not met. Now it shows an empty tooltip. I don't want a tooltip when the condition fails.

Cleaned it a bit

```
<tr class=title="@(item.Cancelled ? "Cancelled" : item.Confirmed ? isBlocked? "blocked date": **no title attribute here** :"Confirm needed") ">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always perform the following pornography:

```
<tr @Html.Raw(item.Cancelled ? "title=\"Cancelled\"" : item.Confirmed ? isBlocked ? "title=\"blocked date\"": "" : "title=\"Confirm needed\"")>
```

But I would recommend you writing a custom helper to generate this `td` element:

```
@using (Html.Td(item, isBlocked))
{
    <div>some contents for the td</div>
}
```

like this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private class TdElement : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;
        private bool _disposed;

        public TdElement(ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            if (viewContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("viewContext");
            }
            _viewContext = viewContext;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this._disposed)
            {
                _disposed = true;
                _viewContext.Writer.Write("</td>");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable Td(this HtmlHelper html, ItemViewModel item, bool isBlocked)
    {
        var td = new TagBuilder("td");
        var title = item.Cancelled 
            ? "Cancelled" 
            : item.Confirmed 
                ? isBlocked 
                    ? "blocked date" 
                    : "" 
                : "Confirm needed";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        {
            td.Attributes["title"] = title;
        }
        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(td.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        var element = new TdElement(html.ViewContext);
        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've chosen for the Raw pornography. Just a habit I guess.

Comment: I have provided an example of how to do it properly but if you feel comfortable with the pornography stick with it.

Comment: Thanks for the proper example. Indeed that looks and feels less dirty.